# Best practices when editing form with emberjs

Tags: forms, ember.js

Is there any good solutions when editing a form to save the model only if the user clicked on the save button and retrieve the old datas if the user canceled the action ?

I've seen some solutions like duplicating the object that is data-binded with each form fields and set the the initial object with the duplicated one when it is saved.

If you could give answers without using ember data could be great.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you would prefer a solution that doesn't use ember-data, but I would argue that using ember-data is best practices. Here is a solution using ember-data because I imagine a lot of people may come across this question...

If you set up your route as follows, it will do exactly that.

```
App.CommentEditRoute = Em.Route.extend({

  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('comment', params.comment_id);
  },

  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      var model = this.get('controller.content');

      if (model.get('isDirty')) {
        model.rollback();
      }
    }
  },

});
```

If you call `this.get('content').save()` in the controller (because the user clicked the save button) it will persist the changes through the adapter and `isDirty` will be set to `false`. Thus, the model will not rollback. Otherwise, if you did not call `this.get('content').save()` in the controller, the `isDirty` property will be `true` and the unsaved changes will be discarded. See the [DS.Model docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html) for more info.

`willTransition` is an event automatically called when the route is about to change - you don't have to call it directly.

Your controller might look like this:

```
App.CommentEditController = Em.ObjectController.extend({

  save: function() {
    var _this = this;

    _this.get('content').save().then(function() {
      // Success
      _this.transitionToRoute('comments');
    }, function() {
      // Failure
      Em.assert('Uh oh!');      
    });
  },

  cancel: function() {
    this.transitionToRoute('comments');
  },

});
```

Also, be sure to utilize the default HTML form submission using a proper HTML button or input for submission so you can capture the submission event in your view as follows:

```
App.CommentEditView = Em.View.extend({

  submit: function() {
    this.get('controller').save();
  },

});
```

Comment: Your solution uses ember-data. Xiu explicitly asked for `answers without using ember data`

Comment: Xiu said "could be great", not necessary. I would argue using ember-data is best practices, which the question asked for. I edited my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Indeed, I rather preferred using ember data but the fact is the project I'm currently working on do not implement ember-data :( ! Anyway, I keep you answer if we migrate to ember-data ;). As I can see, you're playing with the router but the form I'm editing is not linked to any router. Actually, the route looks like this : http://mywebsite.com/template This page contains multiple forms that are also not linked to any route. How can I manage your solution and can you this time give an answer without using ember-data